# Searching through Array for 2 values next o each other

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm working on solution for a problem which I've solved in C#, but now I'm porting my code to F#. I've got a byte array and I need to search two values (x, y) in this array. When I find `x`, it needs to be checked: if `y` is on next index, we have a match. And if `y` isn't on the next index, the search will continue. How should I solve this problem? I've tried to use `Array.findIndex`, but without success because I don't know how to continue the search when `y` is not on next index.

EDIT:

```
public void GetValue(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] temp = new byte[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] == Adress[0] && data[i + 1] == Adress[1])
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
                    {
                        temp[j] = data[j + i + 2];
                    }
                    Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0) * 0.01;
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Don't have time to write a complete answer, but look at the [`Seq.pairwise`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.pairwise%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function. There's a corresponding function in the `Array` module called `Array.pairwise`, but the online docs haven't yet been updated to mention it. That will turn the array `[| 1; 2; 3; 4 |]` into `[| (1,2); (2,3); (3,4) |]`. Then you can do a `findIndex` or `tryFindIndex` on it to see where the newly-generated array has two identical numbers in its tuple.

Comment: can u post the C# code and/or also input and desired output examples?

Comment: I thought about pairing but in my case but It's only correct if this is on index 0 and 1, there will be no match if x s on index 1 and y on index 2.

Comment: @MateuszAd You should try it out with an Array like this and see what it does:  `Array.pairwise [|1;2;2;3;4|]` .

Comment: Sorry, You've got 100% right I didnt understand this function, I thougth its only splits array in pairs this is waht i wanted.

Comment: @MateuszAd that is `Array.partition`, which can be also quite handy, as it can split into arbitrary units.

Comment: Your C# method will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the data is not found; you run ``i`` up to ``data.Length - 1`` but then access ``data[j + i + 2]``…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make this into  a function easily:

```
let bytes = [| 104uy; 101uy; 108uy; 108uy; 111uy |]

bytes 
|> Array.pairwise
|> Array.findIndex (fun x -> fst x = snd x)
//2
```

Comment: This solution is what i wanted. Im amazed how clean solution can be in functional programming

Comment: @MateuszAd - If this answer helped you solve the problem, then you should click the checkmark under the score to mark it as accepted. That lets anyone else who finds your question in a search, later on, know that it was answered correctly, and so if they have the same problem they'll be able to find the answer.

Comment: I would deconstruct the pair `fun (x,y) -> x = y` rather than using `fst` and `snd`.

Comment: I agree. Def more idiomatic, by the time my brain gets there I already typed out fun x ->...

Answer (score 3):

You already have your accepted answer, but I was struck by your comment "Im amazed how clean solution can be in functional programming".

You could have written your C# code functionally too:

```
var index = Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                      .Zip(bytes.Zip(bytes.Skip(1)))
                      .Where(triplet => triplet.Item2.Item1 == triplet.Item2.Item2)
                      .Select(triplet => triplet.Item1)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                      .First();
```

If you take that a bit further you can create some extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<A, A>> Pairwise<A>(this IEnumerable<A> self) =>
        self.Zip(self.Skip(1));

    public static int IndexOf<A>(this IEnumerable<A> self, Func<A, bool> f) =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                  .Zip(self)
                  .Where(x => f(x.Item2))
                  .Select(x => x.Item1)
                  .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                  .FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Which then would give you almost exactly the same code as the F# version you accepted:

```
var index = bytes.Pairwise()
                 .IndexOf(x => x.Item1 == x.Item2);
```

C# can be a very powerful functional language in its own right.  If you have projects that are mixing C# and F# and you want your C# to look as nice as your F then you might want to try [my functional base class library for C#](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/).

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code could be translated to F# as follows (with better index check so you don't run over the data array's bounds):

```
let getValue (a : _ []) (d : _ []) =
    let rec aux i =
        if i > data.Length - 6 then nan
        elif d.[i] = a.[0] && d.[i + 1] = a.[1] then
            0.01 * float (System.BitConverter.ToInt32 (d, i + 2))
        else aux (i + 1)
    aux 0

let value = getValue address data
```

But since reusing library functions can make for easier readable code compared to hand-rolled recursive loops, we can also use `Array.pairwise` as suggested:

```
let getValue2 (a : byte []) d =
    d |> Array.pairwise
      |> Array.tryFindIndex (fun (x, y) -> x = a.[0] && y = a.[1])
      |> Option.map (fun i ->
          0.01 * float (System.BitConverter.ToInt32 (d, i + 2)))
      |> function None -> nan | Some v -> v
```